# Align an element partway to the right

Tags: html, css

I want to align some text using div align= "right" but I don't want it all the way to the right. Is there any way to specify how far right I want the text to be. It seems simple enough but I wasn't able to find out how to do this.

Thank you.

Comment: use `padding` in css to do that

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
.divClass {
    padding-right: 50px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

The padding will push everything inside the div to the left whatever distance you would like. You can also specify in %, pt, em, in, cm...

Answer (score 2):

You can set `text-align: right` in the CSS, and `padding-right: 30px` on the element so it doesn't appear on the extreme right of the element.

If you don't want your element to grow by the padding, you can use `box-sizing: border-box` on it so the padding is included in its width.

Answer (score 1):

For customizing the `div align = 'right'` tag in HTML, you can use CSS class in HTML code. So, you can try this :

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
   p.first {

        padding-right: 100px;
        text-align:right;
        background-color: gray; 
        color:red;

     }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h2>Embedding CSS Classes</h2>
    <p class="first">This is the p.first paragraph</p>
    <div align ="right">This isnot formatted Sentence</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I Hope you got what you'd needed!